# Java md5, the PHP way

Tags: java, md5

I have been working on this for hours, but I can't get it to work.

Basically I am developing a REST client in Java for a REST server in PHP. Both the client and the server have to compute the md5 of a string and the server will compare them for authentication (kinda).

On the server, the PHP code is:

```
md5("getTokenapi_keybf8ddfs845jhre980543jhsjfro93fd8capi_ver1tokeniud9ER£jdfff");
```

that generates:

```
4d7b2e42c3dfd11de3e77b9fe2211b87
```

Nice!

Here is the code for the client:

```
import java.security.*;
....
String s = "getTokenapi_keybf8ddfs845jhre980543jhsjfro93fd8capi_ver1tokeniud9ER£jdfff";
byte[] bytesOfMessage = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);    

System.out.println("String2: " + thedigest);        
System.out.println("String3: " + new String(thedigest));
```

That generates:

```
String2: [B@42e816
String3: M{.B�����{��!�
```

How can I get Java to compute the md5 sum the same way PHP does, please?

Thanks, 
Dan

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
public static String md5(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String result = input;
    if(input != null) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); //or "SHA-1"
        md.update(input.getBytes());
        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
        result = hash.toString(16);
        while(result.length() < 32) { //40 for SHA-1
            result = "0" + result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

code from http://web.archive.org/web/20140209230440/http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-make-java-md5-and-sha-1-hashes-compatible-with-php-or-mysql/

Comment: Thanks, I found that myself straight after writing the question. And it works.

Answer (score 4):

Found myself:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
..
public static String md5(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String result = input;
        if(input != null) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); //or "SHA-1"
            md.update(input.getBytes());
            BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
            result = hash.toString(16);
            if ((result.length() % 2) != 0) {
                result = "0" + result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Source: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-make-java-md5-and-sha-1-hashes-compatible-with-php-or-mysql/

Comment: Lol i deleted my post, 3 people answering this question with the same answer is kinda ridiculous ^^

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting the raw md5 output, which is just a bunch of bytes. You would get the same result in php if you said md5("some string", true).

You need to convert the bytes to ascii characters instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **convert** the result into the HEX representation. This is how it is done in [Fast MD5 library](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php):

```
    private static final char[] HEX_CHARS = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
            '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', };

    /**
     * Turns array of bytes into string representing each byte as unsigned hex
     * number.
     * 
     * @param hash
     *            Array of bytes to convert to hex-string
     * @return Generated hex string
     */
    public static String asHex(byte hash[]) {
        char buf[] = new char[hash.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
            buf[x++] = HEX_CHARS[(hash[i] >>> 4) & 0xf];
            buf[x++] = HEX_CHARS[hash[i] & 0xf];
        }
        return new String(buf);
    }
```

So you will need to call `System.out.println("String3: " + asHex(thedigest));`

Answer (score 1):

if you use spring security framework , just do :

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.*

new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword("myWord",null)
```

The same result as `PHP::md5()`. **I confirm**

[See more examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/9654817fd85c5081c3874060ea30b9bec9a7934e/core/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/Md5PasswordEncoderTests.java)