# Different MD5 results

Tags: java, php, md5

I am porting an application developed in Java struts to PHP, the database is in MySQL,

The PHP, MySQL or online MD5 produces this for NtbPq :

```
db94207ab2924504e0f590682645258a
```

Where as the application has produced this for same password:

```
db94207ab292454e0f590682645258a
              ^
```

Notice the missing 1 character. Now the Java application works perfectly and logs the user but PHP cannot verify and says it doesn't match with PHP md5 function.

Is there any solution I can use 31 char md5 by java to verify in PHP?

**EDIT : problem is i have not developed the java application, now there are over 400 users, which i want to port in php, i dont know a thing about java, i just want to veryfy those 31 character md5 in php**

Comment: A MD5 hash should have 32 digits (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) so it's being truncated somewhere in your code.  Can you paste the particular PHP function that generates it?

Comment: Try using different algorithm for password hashing, since MD5 is not secure.

Comment: It's meant to be 32 digits, and without the code it's very hard to tell what's causing the truncation. Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183646/java-md5-the-php-way)

Comment: @Justinas It's not the problem he can't change the algorithm if he want porting the users

Comment: the java struts application is generation the 31 character md5, i don't have experience of java, my application works perfectly with 32 character md5 but i want to port the mysql database created earlier by java md5 and use php to login users

Comment: If it's always removing character at same place, than in PHP generate MD5 and remove that character too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the hex conversion you're using in the application is failing if the leading nybble of a byte is 0. This is probably because you've got hex conversion code within the application itself, rather than using a standard library.

Solution: find the hex conversion code, rip it out, and use a standard library instead. For example, as it seems by your comment that it's the Java code which is producing the wrong result (your post isn't very clear) you could use [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

As noted in comments, however, it would be worth trying to avoid using MD5 anyway. That may or may not be feasible right now, but it should be on your medium-term roadmap.

EDIT: As a temporary measure, you could write your own PHP code to emulate the brokenness. Basically, you need to perform the normal MD5 hashing, then take the hex result and remove any '0' from it which occurs in an even position. So for example "ab0120" would end up as "ab120" - because the first '0' is in position 2, but the last '0' is in position 5. Alternatively, perform the hex conversion yourself, converting one byte at a time and trimming any leading '0' character from each two-character result. This code should be removed as quickly as possible, and *only* used to validate that users with broken stored MD5 hashes are valid.

Comment: problem is i have not developed the java application, now there are over 400 users, which i want to port in php, i dont know a thing about java

Comment: @Neox: Fundamentally, that Java code is broken. Are you saying you've got a load of *stored* broken MD5 sums? (It's really unclear what situation you're in.)

Comment: I have 400+ users stored in mysql db with 31 character md5 generated by java application which needs to be ported in php application, thats the main problem

Comment: @Neox: I would recommend that you get those users to sign in again so you can store the *valid* MD5 sum (or better yet, upgrade to a different cryptographic hash). Porting the brokenness seems like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: i agree, i was going to implement users to change password and make it bcrypt once they login in php application, to fix the broken hash i have to create new module in java , which i have no knowledge of , thats why i was checking if i can use the broken hash in php to atleast verify the users

Comment: Thanks, here is another example: password: .0desk.  should be : ec6eb7022fbaaf6e5a45dbf4dadcaa63  but it becomes ec6eb722fbaaf6e5a45dbf4dadcaa63

Comment: @Neox: Yes, it would. See my edit - basically it's a matter of removing the "0"s which occur as the leading character in any hex pair.

Comment: @Neox: You generate the broken hash in PHP and try to verify against that as well as the valid hash - that's what my edit is about (reproducing the broken hash in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could possibly help you:
[Java md5, the PHP way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183646/java-md5-the-php-way)

Seems to me like the very same problem.

Comment: you should've marked it as duplicate instead of asnwering with a link to the question.

Comment: I'm pretty unfledged with giving answers here. And I couldn't find any option to mark as duplicate - sorry for that.

Comment: @MightyPork: I don't think it's a duplicate at all, to be honest.

Comment: i dont want to fix the java application, i just want to use the md5 generated for over 400 users by this java application to use in my php application

Answer (score 0):

Hi what I would do is store the md5 hash in your db and whenever you detect a login of that specific user convert it to PBKDF2 (its more secure). Then you can delete the old md5.

This guide shows you how to do it.

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode

Comment: But before he can do that a user must login first, the problem the users can't login

Comment: I agree it doesn't solve his current problem. just a suggestion for the future

Comment: yes thats the problem, i cant verify the login using 31 character md5

Comment: You have to look to the part producing the hash code and try to do the same in php. In future do what @Arno_Geismar suggested.

Comment: yes i had planned to integrate bcrypt in future, but for now i need the users to atleast verify the login, i'll check the java code and post it here, as i dont understand java i need some help here.